# Trying to download a file with express from the server as client -> Unexpected token �

Tags: node.js, express

currently I am always running in the same [error](https://i.gyazo.com/552eb36def1eb7fab9ea12f0f181ff9e.png) and I do not find any solution. I am trying to download a file from the server as a client with express.
This is the code serverside:

```
// Set up
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var app = express();                               
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                     
var morgan = require('morgan');             
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); 
var cors = require('cors');

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Sharify');

app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'true' }));            
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); 
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT, GET');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

app.get('/api/download/:projectid/:filename', function (req, res) {
    res.download(__dirname + '/uploads/' + req.params.projectid + '/' + req.params.filename);    
});
```

Clientside it is getting called by this:

```
downloadFile(file)
{
  return new Promise(resolve => {
       this.http.get('http://localhost:27017/api/download/' + file.projectID + "/" + file.fileName)
           .map(res => res.json())
           .subscribe(data => {
               resolve(this.data);
           });
   });        
}
```

I always get this error in the developer console: https://gyazo.com/552eb36def1eb7fab9ea12f0f181ff9e
Does someone know a solution for that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the downloaded file contain valid JSON?

Comment: It is just a .jpg

Comment: So why are you using `res.json()`?

Comment: What should I take instead? You are right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `this.http.get()` is, but if it's based on [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Making_fetch_requests), you probably want to use [`res.blob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob) instead of `res.json()` (which is only meant for JSON responses, but yours is a JPEG file).

You likely also have to resolve `data`, not `this.data`:

```
.subscribe(data => {
  resolve(data);
});
```

Comment: I changed the code to:
    return new Promise(resolve => {
                this.http.get('http://localhost:27017/api/download/' + file.projectID + "/" + file.fileName)
                    .map(res => res.blob())
                    .subscribe(data => {
                       resolve(this.data);
                    });
            });

Getting this error now: https://gyazo.com/e7d15e3d794f86cc50a410baacefea0b

Yes, the http.get() is based on fetch ;)

Comment: Also changed the "this.data". Getting the blob error now, mentioned before. Currently googling for the blob error.

Comment: I don't understand why it's stating that the _request_ body has a wrong type, since we're dealing with a _response_. I assume that `.map().subscribe()` is RxJS or something like that?

Comment: Yes, it is rxjs

Comment: So what exactly is `this.http.get()`?

Comment: It is calling the server to do a specific command. Here is an example how I handle it with mongodb(mongoose):

app.get('/api/companies/:id', function (req, res) {
    Company.findById(req.params.id, function (err, company) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(company);
    });
});

Edit: So actually I do a request and get the answer from the server.

Comment: Yeah I understand what it does, but how is it implemented? Also, instead of using `res.download()` (in Express), have you tried `res.sendFile()`? The code you're posting in your comment _does_ return JSON (unless there's an error), but in your question you are retrieving a JPEG file...?

Comment: I tried both. res.download() and res.sendFile() returns the same error. I am refering on a .jpg. Here is a the console log of my server: https://gyazo.com/28c0b8070b0ac6afe467d770563578a7

Comment: That all looks okay (it has the correct file extension, so it will have the correct `Content-Type` header set in the response). I'm beginning to suspect `this.http.get()`.

Comment: Probably. Looking to find an alternative to this.http.get()